# What is the probability of 4 players all getting a straight in a game of 5 card poker

Tags: probability, statistics, gambling, poker

Was playing a silly game of Texas Holdem when every player that was still in got a straight: 
One player was out, the others all got straight
[image: One player was out, the others all got straight]

And I was wondering what would be the chance of this occurring? Cheers.

Comment: In casual card games, shuffling between hands is often inadequate to randomize the deck, or even to remove overt evidence of patterns left over from the previous hand. [In the previous hand, some effort was expended to put cards into a meaningful order, rather than a random (information free) order.] It takes about six riffle shuffles to get near to randomness. So computations based on equally-likely models do not apply to these games. // I'm not saying I doubt this remarkable event happened, but it may not have happened by chance alone.

Comment: Appears the board had a straight.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

In Texas Hold'em, I think there are five common cards, and each player has two more cards.  Each player thus has seven cards, from which to choose five that makes his hand.

I ran this for a million deals, and all four players could form a straight in 3724, or once every 268 deals.  I expect 3724 might vary by $\pm120$ by chance.

The chance that the common cards form a straight by themselves is about 1 in 282, or 3546 in a million.

So it's usually because the common cards are a straight.

Comment: Please note that all the players have the 7 of hearts and the 3 of spades. Three players have the 4 of clubs, three players have the 6 of clubs, and two players have the 5 of spades. So yes, the common cards are a straight.

Comment: @Bram28 I believe you are correct.  It would have been nice for the OP to state that explicitly.